# FileSystemWatcher event not triggered from Mac users

Tags: macos, powershell, filesystemwatcher

The following script runs on a Windows 7 SP1 PC monitoring a folder that is shared out. Mac users, running fairly up to date iMacs/MacbookPros copy files to the share.

```
$fsw = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher -Property @{
    Path = "c:\temp"
    IncludeSubdirectories = $false 
}

$event = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $fsw –EventName Created -SourceIdentifier fsw -Action {
    if ((Test-Path -Path $EventArgs.FullPath -PathType leaf) -And ($EventArgs.Name -Like "*.jpg")) {

        $imageSource = $EventArgs.FullPath
        Write-Host "Processing File:" $imageSource
    }
}
```

When Mac users copy a single file, the event is triggered. If multiple files are copied, then the event is not triggered at all or only one event occurs.

Any ideas? When copying files to the share from a Windows machine I have no problem.